# Unable to install Java Runtime (6) on Mac

Tags: java, macos, installation, runtime

I'm having a problem of installing java SE runtime 6 on mac, without that, I can't open my eclipse or install Intellij. However, I download the .dmg through an Apple - Java link, but it just doesn't install!

And there's no error message, just the page of falling installation.

[image]

I really don't know how to solve it.

This is kind of an update of my problem... I used to have Java SE runtime 6 and tried to install jdk 1.8 and failed. Same picture appeared. Just said failed installing with no error messages. I guessed might be a conflicts? and deleted Java 6 and basically can't run eclipse & Intellij (this solved thought) I still have java 1.7 here.

I just can't figure out why I can't install (or reinstall) java 1.6 or java 1.8. What could be the problem?

Some system updates:
if I do: "which java":

```
/usr/bin/java
```

if "echo $JAVA_HOME":

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

if java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
```

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

What could be possibly wrong?!!!????
God

Comment: @chrylis - that is not correct. I am running Apple Java 6 on Yosemite right now

Comment: what version of OS X are you using?

Comment: Run the Console.app and check the system.log for diagnostics

Comment: Also, what do you get if you try to run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` in Terminal.app?

Comment: @SteveC It said: Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.7.0_51, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: How did you delete Java 6?  What are the contents of /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions?  The first directory is where Apple installs Java 6, and the second (Versions) directory should contain a bunch of symbolic links to directories in the first. e.g.  /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk

Answer (score 1):

You need to get Java directly from Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) as Apple stopped supporting Java some time ago.  Unless you have pressing reasons for using Java 6 I suggest also installing at least Java 7, although you can have all three versions installed and select the appropriate version for the app you want to run/develop.

**Edit** Also, if you want to use Eclipse or IntelliJ (go for IntelliJ) you want to get the JDK and not the "runtime" (JRE).

Comment: But it prompted that "You need Java SE Runtime 6" to install eclipse or Intellij...I'm confused.

Comment: Apple is still supporting Java 6 in a limited way. They did release a new version earlier this year (2014).

Comment: @JudyJiang:  The JDK (Java Development Kit) does include the JRE, but not the other way around.  The JDK is simply the JRE + the stuff needed to compile Java code, so Eclipse/IntelliJ require a JDK.  I just mentioned that because the Java download site has always been confusing and Oracle only seems to make it worse.  In fact I have fixed my download link above to point to a better download page (the previous page only let you download Java 8)  The new link is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: @SteveC: Yes, but Apple has always been very slow with Java updates. Oracle releases patches every few weeks, Apple does it a few times a year.